# Does vacuum displacement field imply space filled with Planck particle/antiparticle pairs?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, charge, vacuum, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

Consider natural [Gaussian units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units) such that $\hbar=c=1$ and the electron charge $e=\sqrt{\alpha}$ where $\alpha\approx1/137$ is the fine structure constant.

In Gaussian units the vacuum displacement field $\vec{D}$ is identical to the applied electric field $\vec{E}$ so that
$$\vec{D}=\vec{E}.\tag{1}$$
Let us assume that in each small volume of space, $L^3$, there are charges $+q$ and $-q$ both with a mass $M$.

The vacuum displacement field, which is the vacuum polarization per unit volume, is given by
$$\vec{D}=q\times\frac{q\vec{E}}{M}\cdot T^2\times\frac{1}{L^3},\tag{2}$$
where the middle term is the separation distance of each pair of charges due to their acceleration in the electric field $\vec{E}$ during time $T$.

According to the quantum uncertainty principle in natural units $T = L = 1/M$ so that we find
$$\vec{D}=q^2\vec{E}.\tag{3}$$
Thus it seems that there must be masses $M$ with charges $q=+1,-1$ at each point in space in order to satisfy Eqn.$(1)$. The charge $q$ is $e/\sqrt{\alpha}=11.7e$.

Could the masses $M$ at each point in space be Planck masses with dimensions given by the Planck length $10^{-33}$ cm?

The Planck masses could have the fundamental charge $e$ if at the Planck energy the electromagnetic force is unified with the other forces so that $e=\sqrt{\alpha}=1$.

The pairs of Planck masses can be generated by positive-energy zero point modes with wavelengths down to the Planck length. If the Planck masses consist of matter and antimatter then according to the [Feynman-Stueckelberg interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiparticle#Feynman%E2%80%93Stueckelberg_interpretation) the antimatter can be considered as having negative mass. Thus the combined gravitational mass of each pair is zero so that space can remain flat.

Comment: The Planck mass is where the Compton wavelength recedes behind the Schwarzschild horizon of a particle. What does it have to do with your odd model?

Comment: The Planck mass is mentioned as it is equivalent to the smallest length known to physics i.e. the Planck length $10^{-33}$cm.  Also I believe that if space is full of Planck masses with positive and negative unit charge then electric and magnetic fields produce a gravitational field due to the EM field accelerating the Planck masses (Einstein's Equivalence Principle). In this manner the electrostatic energy of any charged particle is exactly balanced by its gravitational energy. This solves the classical problem of a charged point particle having an infinite electrostatic energy.

Comment: There is a whiff of contradiction, though, talking about classical entities, as the Planck  length is  *defined* through hbar...